# WebResponse reading with callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, callback, webclient, uwp, webresponse

I have an app where the user can choose to download all content and this was done with this method on other platforms

```
 resp.GetResponseStream().BeginRead(mBuffer, 0, 1448, new AsyncCallback(EndRead), resp);
```

but a BeginRead-method is not present in the .NET framework used by UWP applications. I need a way to do this in the same way as the other platforms do it, so I can use the callback-function for progressbar updating.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not put tags in ttile if it not neede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to do this in the same way as the other platforms do it, so I can use the callback-function for progressbar updating.

You can use this way as a workaround:

```
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.bing.com");

        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        var stream = await response.GetResponseStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

        // add callback actions here
```